# Proof for functoriality of weighted colimit formula?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $\mathsf D \overset{K}{\leftarrow} \mathsf C \overset{F}{\to} \mathsf E$ be functors. Suppose we define a pointwise left Kan extension of $F$ along $K$ on objects by the colimit of the composite $K_{/d}\to \mathsf C\to \mathsf E$.

What is a (slick) way to prove the functoriality of this assignment? Particularly, how can we write a pointwise left Kan extension as a composite of functors?

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that
$$
\text{Lan}_KF(d) \cong \int^{c\in\sf C} \hom(Kc,d)\cdot Fc
$$
whenever this colimit exists, seems to be the slickest way. More generally, if $F : {\sf C}\to {\sf E}$ is a diagram of $\cal V$-categories and $W : {\sf C}^\text{op}\times{\sf D} \to \cal V$ is a weight, the weighted colimit $d\mapsto [W\otimes F](d)$ is the coend
$$
\int^{c\in \sf C} W(c,d)\cdot Fc
$$
and in both cases this is functorial in the weight $W$, in the diagram $F$, and in the argument $d$ as a simple consequence of the functoriality of coends.

Comment: I prefer not to use coends yet. I am writing some notes which introduce pointwise Kan extensions immediately after limits weighted by a functor without mentioning the example of bifunctors.

Comment: As you already know, the weighted colimit functor is defined by a universal property; the functoriality (on the weight, and on the diagram) of $\{-,-\}$ and $-\otimes-$ can be proved with the universal property, as functoriaity contraints follow from a uniqueness request. It's the opposite of a slick proof though. Every other sleight of hand I know, like relative adjoints, requires quite a lot of terminology to define weighted colimits intrinsically. Coends are a rather nice compromise.

Comment: Now, please try to be more specific about what you can or can't use in this proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your comments. I'm not sure how specific I can be, but I would like to avoid (co)ends and the explicit use of (co)tensors. I was hoping for some elementary composite $\mathsf D\overset{\varphi-}{\to} \mathsf{Cat}_{/\mathsf C}\overset{F_\ast}{\to} \mathsf{Cat}_{/\mathsf E}\overset{\varinjlim}{\to} \mathsf E$ taking an object $d$ to the discrete opfibration associated to $\mathsf{D}(F-,d)$ (or just the slice $F_{/d}$, then to post-composition with $F$, and to the colimit, except a composite which makes sense...